# meaning of "Be gone image from my mind!!"

Tags: meaning

I was talking to someone about something and she said:

> Uh, Be gone image from my mind!!

What does it mean?

Comment: It means "Uh...  Be gone, image, from my mind!"  (it just needed some extra punctuation).

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: There's nothing particularly idiomatic about it. "Be gone" is a command: "Go away!" The person is telling the image in her mind to go away. It is not something she wants to imagine.

Answer (score 1):

**[Begone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/begone)**

> intransitive verb :  to go away :  depart —used especially in the
>   imperative

My Oxford dictionary gives **Begone** as a poetical interjection meaning 'go away at once!' 
People tend, in my experience, to use 'begone' when they intend to be [**melodramatic**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/melodrama) for comedic effect.

Comment: ...or are a "bit mental," as the Brits like to say.

Comment: We do, or at least some of us do. I started to write that answer as a comment describing the over-dramatic drama-llama implications of telling images to 'begone!', but decided an answer with a couple of links might be simpler!